# New unread messages in IMAP not showing up in list

Tags: python, imap

I am using `imaplib` to try and fetch new unread messages from an IMAP server.  When I first connect, I properly get all of the unread messages.  However, new mesages that arrive after I connect will not show up in the results of searching on `(UNSEEN)`.

I thought at first I would simply need to send a `NOOP` with `noop()` before running the search again, but that is not helping.  Same with `recent()` and `check()` in imaplib. Is there something else I need to do to refresh the connection on my client side?

Comment: What email server?  Are you using Yahoo?

Comment: Some servers never update their view after you connect; they expect clients to connect, do their work, disconnect, and poll again later.  Yahoo works this way.  Maybe office365 does as well.  Try re-`SELECT`ing the folder you're in.