# Python email checker script shows only unread messages, but not ones received since the program was opened

Tags: python, email, imap

I'm writing a program, and part of it is to check for new emails every 10 seconds. It does fine and only shows me unread messages when I start the program, but on its next loop it doesn't show newly sent messages since the program was opened. Is there some particular reason, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** Yes, I've sent messages to the account in question *after* the program has started, and let it sit for a few minutes, and still get nothing

```
while(1):
        time.sleep(10)
        print("\n\nRefreshing....")

        rv, data = M.search(None, 'UNSEEN') #Check for new messages, which works fine the first run
        
        print(rv)
        print(data)
        if rv != 'OK':
            print("No messages found!")
            return

        for num in data[0].split():
            print("num: " + str(num))
            rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
            if rv != 'OK':
                print("ERROR getting message", num)
                return

            msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
            hdr = email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject']))
            subject = str(hdr)
            
            print('Message: %s\n' % (subject))
            if "blabla" in subject:
                 #do stuff here
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].The interesting bits are no doubt inside of `M.search`, which we cannot see.

Comment: You may have to reconnect each time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199058/new-unread-messages-in-imap-not-showing-up-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, I suppose… what you're seeing is an effect of IMAP's message numbering synchronisation.

When you open a mailbox, the server assigns numbers 1, 2, 3… to the messages, and that numbering is stable for as long as the client only uses certain commands. Most/all servers delay telling the client about new mail until they're permitted to change the numbers (and there are reasons for that). `SEARCH` is one of the (four) commands that keep stable numbers. Sending a `NOOP` before each search would solve the bug, switching from `SEARCH` to `UID SEARCH` ditto.